# JavaScript regex test not begening with attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test words string which don't begin with a specific word,

```
var content = 'special-src="http://www.link.com" ';
var src = new RegExp(/\b(?!special-)\w*src=*\b/g);
console.log(src.test(content));
```

This should console a false, but it's not.

But, if I remove the - from the regex and content, the result is fine so I guess this is kind of escaping issue ?

Comment: Why do you use `global` flag? Do you need to test every word in a string and not the string itself?

Comment: @VisioN yes I have to test all the words;

Comment: I suggest you add more examples in question to make it clear

Comment: does it have to be regex? javascript strings have a [startsWith() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a negative lookbehind `(?<!special-)`, not negative lookahead `(?!special-)`. I've got it working in Regex Workbench, but Javascript doesn't support this natively.

This approach looks like it might work: http://davidchin.me/blog/simulate-regex-lookbehind-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var content = 'special-src="http://www.link.com" ';
var src = /^(?!special\-)\w*src=.*$/g;
console.log(src.test(content));
```

**UPDATE**

There was a mistake in the expression, should be **!?** instead **?!**. The correct code is

```
var content = 'special-src="http://www.link.com" ';
var src = /^(!?special\-)\w*src=.*$/g;
console.log(src.test(content));
```

Comment: no cause if you have a space before the src it wont return true